# How can I use user and password variables in my json request?

Tags: json, angular

[Pic 1: Angular 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWqIY.png)

In the first picture  I have my user input and I can display in the console variables username and password. In the second picture I am sending username and password with my token. How can I use the username and password from first picture and send those with my header? Please help.

[Pic 2: json request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzSno.png)

Answer (score 0):

Headers class is constant so when you use it only is possible set headers while you are using new statement. i.e.

```
new Headers({header:value}) 
new Headers().append('header', 'value');
```

However this not work because is a constants

```
let headers = new Header();
headers.append('header','value')
```

You only can do thing as

```
new Headers({header:btoa(userna + ':' + password)});
```

HTML

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(myForm)">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password"
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

COMPONENT

```
onSubmit(form) {
   if(form.valid) {
      console.log(form.control.username);
      console.log(form.control.password);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have it like this:  let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password) });
    
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });   but it still does not load my username and password from the input. Do you know how I can achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Is the problem you can't retrieve login and password from your child component ?

Comment: Could I see the HTML please?

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to do that without making global classes? Thanks.

Comment: '
<form (submit)="loginUser($event)">
  <div class="input">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password">
  </div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </div>
</form>'

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you are looking for your logins data, le proper way is to emit an event like this :

login-form component:

```
@output
onLogin : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

login(e){
***
this.onLogin.emit({username:username,password:password});
}
```

app component.html

```
<login-form (onLogin)="getData($event)"></login-form>
```

here "$event" represent your object "{username:username,password:password}";

otherwise you can store datas in a variable and run "getData" when you want.

Other suggestions:
Use angular reactive-forms like this :https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#add-a-formgroup
maybe run your xhr from angular services.